# CLANG:"__declspec(dllimport) cannot be applied to a non-inline function" error in my C Program

Tags: c, windows, clang, game-engine

So... I was creating my own game engine following the Kohi Game Engine Series as all other series did not work on YouTube but then I stumbled across an error... The error is:

```
Error: __declspec(dllimport) cannot be applied to a non-inline function
```

I got this error while writing in C with Clang as my compiler, here are my compiler details:

```
clang version 17.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

Here is my code:

```
ALM_API void log_output(LogLevel level, const char* message, ...) {
```

ALM_API = __declspec(dllimport) and also if I do try remove ALM_API it will also through an error since I have created this function in another file and in this file I am giving the function commands. (Keep in mind I did add '}' at the end of the function!)

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: dllimport tells the compiler that the function lives elsewhere, inside another library.  So it doesn't expect a definition of that function, that doesn't make sense.  Only a declaration makes sense.  Maybe it should be dllexport, it isn't obvious from the question.